# How to access an item "oranges" in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, linux, console

I want to get something like this: `oranges`

However no output is displayed. I tried printing via console and it doesn't work.

```
var array2 = ["Banana", ["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]];
```

Comment: can you give us your closest try please

Comment: array2[1][1][0];

Comment: @JoshuaIbemgbo That's what you need to use, and it works... so what's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/608639), [How to access a element in JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15995780/608639), [JavaScript access array elements by object value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30194237/608639), [How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8238456/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since the desired fruit resides inside into third level, you have to use 3 indexes. Try `array2[1][1][0]`.

Step by step:

```
array2[1]        => ["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]
array2[1][1]     => ["Oranges"]
array2[1][1][0]  => Oranges
```

```js
var array2 = ["Banana", ["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]];

console.log(array2[1][1][0]); // Oranges
```

Comment: Shouldn't questions like this be closed against their canonical dups? What value does this questions and the answers add to the site for future visitors?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on your array

but that's seem like overkill here

```js
var array2 = ["Banana", ["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]];

let [,[,[orange]]] = array2

console.log(orange)
```

I added this answer to inform this way existed, **BUT** [the answer from @Mamum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078789/10153945) is the way to go to when you need to get a small number of values from an array :

```
let orange = array2[1][1][0]
```

Comment: Though your answer is correct, however, in my opinion it is too much of an ask from a person who is learning how to access nested array

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal yeah I know I just wanted to inform that it existed, also upvoted `array2[1][1][0]` since this is the correct one

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts mate!

Comment: Thanks for the assist @bamieh

Comment: I like this one, but maybe it could be a mess for learners. Why don't you include the short `array2[1][1][0]` in your answer? Just in case this answer rise to the top.

Comment: @Emeeus didn't want to steal the answer from Mamun since he was faster than me

Comment: You could add it at the end or something, and cite him for if you wish.

Comment: @Emeeus like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Joshua!

Arrays are accessible starting from index 0, so in order to access the inside array `["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]` you need to write `array2[1]` since it is the second item in the array.

Next you need to access the `["Oranges"]` which is also the second item in that array, resulting in `array2[1][1]`.

Finally since `array2[1][1]` also returns an array containing "Oranges" in its first index (0), you have to write `array2[1][1][0]` which will give you the result

```
console.log(array2[1][1][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays are currently nested, are you sure that's what you want? Since you have a pretty linear list of items here, I would suggest taking the internal arrays out:

```
var array2 = ["Banana", "Apples", "Oranges", "Blueberries"];
```

Array contents can be called by using the index number associated with the item you are trying to select. In this case:

```
console.log(array2[2]);
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is the MDN documentation on JavaScript arrays, for your reference :)